# React-Router not defined UNSAFE_invariant error

Tags: react-router

I want to try to use React-Router but I get an unexpected error.

This is a sample test page. I include via CDN react, react-router, babel and jquery.

A Page1 component shows only a text. The App component try to use Routers component.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test React DOM</title>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/6.9.0/react-router.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/6.9.0/react-router-dom.development.js"></script>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    
        <div id="app-root"></div>
        
        <script type="text/babel">
            const Routes = ReactRouterDOM.Routes;
            const Route  = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
            
            class Page1 extends React.Component
            {
                render()
                {
                    return (
                        <h1>Page 1</h1>
                    );
                }
            }
            
            class App extends React.Component
            {
                render()
                {
                    return (
                        <Routes>
                            <Route path="/" element={<Page1 />} />
                        </Routes>

                    );
                }
            }
            
            jQuery(function ($)
            {
                ReactDOM.render(
                    <App />,
                    document.getElementById('app-root')
                );
            });
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I can remove the Route component, but the result doesn't change, the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'UNSAFE_invariant')
    at useRoutes (hooks.tsx:307:3)
    at Routes (components.tsx:404:10)
    at jp (react-dom.development.min.js:1:140368)
    at react-dom.development.min.js:1:177214
    at Vm (react-dom.development.min.js:1:178589)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.d (react-dom.development.min.js:1:48137)
    at Object.vr (react-dom.development.min.js:1:48462)
    at Cr (react-dom.development.min.js:1:49424)
    at lv (react-dom.development.min.js:1:215321)
    at By (react-dom.development.min.js:1:206186)
```

Comment: `UNSAFE_invariant` is defined in an import from `@remix-run/router`.  I don't have experience using react-router with CDNs but maybe you need to load this script too?

Also I believe `<Routes>` needs to be used inside of a `<Router>` component so it has the routing context.  You will want to replace it with something like `<ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap the App component inside a router like so:

```js
const BrowserRouter = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;

class App extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Page1 />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

If you get another error saying something like `index.tsx:298 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createBrowserHistory')`
It's an error in react-router 6 which I'm not sure how to fix, but you can remove both scripts for react-router and react-router-dom in your code and use this one instead (it's react-router-dom 5):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

or

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.3.4/react-router-dom.js" integrity="sha512-ca9oLJcApFimkKytqbfgdOuIkzCWFQ980sZr9RbW7WWdvlDtwbJ8Ubsya+Yqxk/wgrvqOko0hUKKBm5JtoUVNw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```